# Structured streaming: how the delay will works?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

How the delay will works in Structured streaming jobs. will it create a delay in processing the number of files coming in the stream?

Comment: What delay are you talking about?

Comment: In Spark Structed Streaming, we are trying to aggregate the row values. We are doing this by applying withWatermark(time, delay) and group the column values with duration and slide. When we do this, we observe a delay in the files getting processed. Sample code below,  df.withWatermark(TIMESTAMP, delay)
        .groupBy(window(col((TIMESTAMP), duration, slide), col(<FILENAME>))
        .agg(collect_list(<DATA COLUMN>))

Comment: _"we observe a delay in the files getting processed"_ How do you observe the delay?

Comment: we get only n-4 files getting processed after we push n files. There is delay of latest 3 to 4 files for getting processed.